# How to set initial values for custom inspector fields in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two similar classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Both classes contain a bool:

In Class A:

```
[SerializeField]
private bool _overwrite = true;

public bool overwrite
{
    get { return _overwrite; }
    set { _overwrite = value; }
}
```

In Class B:

```
[SerializeField]
private bool _hide = true;

public bool hide
{
    get { return _hide; }
    set { _hide = value; }
}
```

Both scripts have a `CustomEditor` script. In both Editor scripts, inside the `OnInspectorGUI()` method the following two lines are used to add the respective bool's to the Inspector.

`ClassA.overwrite = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Overwrite", ClassA.overwrite);`

`ClassB.hide = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Hide", ClassB.hide);`

---

When I add ClassA to a GameObject, the "Overwrite" field is unchecked, however when I add ClassB to a GameObject, the "Hide" field is checked.

I don't understand what is different, or what other factor is involved in setting a default / initial value for a property.

Ideally I want them both to be checked by default.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Thanks for your time,

Liam

Answer (score 4):

The [`Reset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) method of MonoBehaviours seems that it will provide the functionality you are looking for.  It will look something like this:

```
void Reset() 
{
    _overwrite = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `grabObject`?

If it is the component variable which you have found a reference to in the `OnEnable` method using the `target` variable of the [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) script, then simply changing your editor scripts to:

```
grabObject.overwrite = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Overwrite", grabObject.overwrite);
```

and:

```
grabObject.hide = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft("Hide", grabObject.hide);
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: apologies! I missed that when copy and pasting. The actual class is called `grabObject`. What you have above is pretty much exactly what I have in my project.